# How to concatenate list to int in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

When using a list, I saw that I cannot add or subtract the sample I took from the list. For example:

---

```
import random

x = random.sample ((1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), k=1 )                      
print(x + 1)
```

---

Why I can’t add into the list I created and how can I get around that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase the value of every item in a list, you can do like:

```
import random
x = random.sample ((1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), k=3 )
print(x)
for index in range(len(x)):
      x[index] = x[index] +1
print(x)
```

In your case, if k is always 1, you can simply like:

```
import random
x = random.sample ((1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), k=1 )
print(x)
x[0] = x[0] + 1
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't concatenate is because the type random.sample is returning is a *list* of size k=1. If you want to be returning an element of your sequence and add to it, you should be using random.choice. It should read something along the lines of:

```
import random
x = random.choice((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))
print(x+1)
```

Comment: sadly, choice only takes two arguments and I need 14

Comment: Then make it one argument:
a=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
and x = random.choice(a)